# Match and insert in a python sorted list

Tags: python, list, sorting, insert

I have a sorted list and I want to insert a string if it matches the pattern in list.

```
Example :

Sorted List
['Amy Dave', 'Dee Waugh', 'Eva A', 'Gin', 'Joy Kola', 'Kay Min', 'Mae', 'Pam Deing']
```

Above list is in sorted order. I need to insert a name in sorted order and also if the name already exist then it should be inserted before the existing name.

```
Example 
Name  'Eva Henry'
```

As Eva is already in the list then after matching the pattern it should be inserted before "Eva A". If name does not match then it should be inserted in sorted order in the list. The output should be like :

```
 Sorted List
    ['Amy Dave', 'Dee Waugh', 'Eva Henry', 'Eva A', 'Gin', 'Joy Kola', 'Kay Min', 'Mae', 'Pam Deing']
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: *"if the name already exist then it should be inserted before the existing name"* Can I ask why this request?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. If it is, please mark it as homework.

Comment: We have this requirement for privileged customer. Yeah its really strange but it needs to be done :(

Comment: What's keeping you from doing it? What have you tried, and what question do you have? "Write my code" is not a suitable question for this forum.

Comment: And what are you paid to do for your customer, if you can't do this for yourself?

Comment: @Alexis right its not write my code forum but this problem is eating my head just seeking some help cause I am unable to think of any solution. I thought of bisect, split but nothing seems to be giving me result and also I am not Guru of Python. 

Might be somebody in circle have faced same issue and know some tricks can share with me.

Comment: No one will have faced this before, because the requirement is ridiculously stupid.  Also, if the user has ever inserted 2 people with the same name, the list isn't really sorted is it?

Comment: @VladtheImpala http://www.thisblogrules.com/2011/09/ranking-the-5-worst-online-universities.html

Comment: If you had a counter that said the number of times it appeared, you could write it out more than once, without storing it more than once.

Comment: @PratapSingh: Why is the client telling YOU the developer how to store the data? This might be one of the times you fire the client :-)

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, there are no stupid questions.  If the names are meant as full names and only the first names are the key for sorting, there always may be some funny idea and the need to solve the problem.  You can use bisect this way:

```
>>> fullnames = ['Amy Dave', 'Dee Waugh', 'Eva A', 'Gin', 'Joy Kola', 'Kay Min', 'Mae', 'Pam Deing']
>>> names = [full.split()[0] for full in fullnames]
>>> names
['Amy', 'Dee', 'Eva', 'Gin', 'Joy', 'Kay', 'Mae', 'Pam']
```

So, we have parallel list of first names that will be used to find the position of another full name `xx` (the first name extracted to `x` the same way as in the previous case):

```
>>> xx = 'Eva Henry'
>>> x = xx.split()[0]
>>> x
'Eva'
```

Now, use bisect to find the wanted position in the first-name list:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> pos = bisect.bisect_left(names, x)
```

Then update both lists:

```
>>> fullnames.insert(pos, xx)
>>> names.insert(pos, x)
```

Here is the result:

```
>>> fullnames
['Amy Dave', 'Dee Waugh', 'Eva Henry', 'Eva A', 'Gin', 'Joy Kola', 'Kay Min', 'Mae', 'Pam Deing']
>>> names
['Amy', 'Dee', 'Eva', 'Eva', 'Gin', 'Joy', 'Kay', 'Mae', 'Pam']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete answer that does what you want, however ridiculous.  I didn't test any edge cases.

```
sorta_sorted_list = ['Amy Dave', 'Dee Waugh', 'Eva A', 'Gin', 'Joy Kola', 'Kay Min', 'Mae', 'Pam Deing']

print sorta_sorted_list

def insert_kinda_sorted(name, sorta_sorted_list):
    new_list = []
    fname = name.split()[0]
    inserted = False
    for index in range(len(sorta_sorted_list)):
        if not inserted:
            if sorta_sorted_list[index].split()[0] == fname:
                new_list.append(name)
                inserted = True
            if sorta_sorted_list[index] > name:
                new_list.append(name)
                inserted = True
        new_list.append(sorta_sorted_list[index])

    return new_list

sorta_sorted_list = insert_kinda_sorted('Eva Henry', sorta_sorted_list)
print sorta_sorted_list

sorta_sorted_list = insert_kinda_sorted('Joe Blow', sorta_sorted_list)
print sorta_sorted_list
```

output is:

```
['Amy Dave', 'Dee Waugh', 'Eva A', 'Gin', 'Joy Kola', 'Kay Min', 'Mae', 'Pam Deing']
['Amy Dave', 'Dee Waugh', 'Eva Henry', 'Eva A', 'Gin', 'Joy Kola', 'Kay Min', 'Mae', 'Pam Deing']
['Amy Dave', 'Dee Waugh', 'Eva Henry', 'Eva A', 'Gin', 'Joe Blow', 'Joy Kola', 'Kay Min', 'Mae', 'Pam Deing']
```

Comment: Why do you help them to commit programming suicide and spread bad code? :-) Sorry your code is fine, I mean the algorithm.

Comment: Yeah...after I reread that, I realized the insort method won't work.  If we're tokenizing the names, we could also create a dictionary where the first token is the key and the value is a list where we push the names into like a stack, then use a flattening function that returns a list (or generator) when needed.

Comment: Excellent point [gecko](http://stackoverflow.com/users/774340/gecko).  If the requirement is as described (and hopefully it's not), a list is not even the right data structure any more.

Comment: Thanks Jgritty and Pepr for your solutions even I found another solution too myself I will post it soon :)

Answer (score 0):

OK I will get down-voted for this but I can't let this stand. This is a terrible design pattern and you should complain strongly if this is homework.

I would store the name as a tuple with a frequency ('Fred Bloggs', 2), or use a dict() or something: just anything but please not this. Google 'python dict ()'.

edit: Actually a dict() isn't ordered is it? Oh well, I fail at life. Shrug.

edit: Also I meant list of tuples.

Comment: Not sure a tuple is the right data structure, as only the FIRST names seem to require matching.

Comment: [heapq](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/heapq.html) is a good option.

Comment: @Jgritty: the second element is the number of times it appears. the first element is the full name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution I think its easy

:

```
#spliting against whitespace
first_name = name.split()

#Stroting the first name of the user
first_name = first_name[0]

#Matching the pattern 
match = re.compile(first_name,re.IGNORECASE)
ind = ''

for i in sort_names:
        if re.match(match, i):
                ind = sort_names.index(i)
                break
                #If name matches for the first time end the loop and do insert name in the sorted list

if ind != '':
        sort_names.insert(ind, val)
        print ""
        print sort_names
else:
        bisect.insort(sort_names, val)
        print sort_names
```